# Using ion-rangeslider with Aurelia CLI

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to use the ion-rangeslider from http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html the problem I seem to be having is I cannot get the css to load and style the slider.  Here is what I have done so far.

after doing

> npm install ion-rangeslider --save-dev

aurelia.json

```
{
   "name": "ion-rangeslider",
   "path": "../node_modules/ion-rangeslider",
   "main": "js/ion.rangeSlider.min",
   "resources": [
      "css/ion.rangeSlider.css",
      "css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css"
    ]
}
```

app.js

```
import {ionRangeSlider} from 'ion-rangeslider';

attached(){
    $('.slider').ionRangeSlider({
      values: [15, 30, 1, 3, 6, 12, 24]
    });
}
```

app.html

```
<input type="text" class="slider" />
```

The outcome of all this looks like this:

[image]

Any help is greatly aappreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. The only thing I needed to add in order to get this working were these two lines in app.html:

```
<require from="ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.css"></require>
<require from="ion-rangeslider/css/ion.rangeSlider.skinHTML5.css"></require>
```

which resulted in:

[image: img]

I have pushed the app [here](https://github.com/JeroenVinke/aurelia-cli-ion-rangeslider)